# Fizz Buzz Boolean return total

Tags: c#

I have a FizzBuzz Assignment thatcounts from 1 to 1000 
if a number is divisible by 3 its fizz
if its divisible by 5 its buzz
and if its divisible by both is fizzbuzz

I managed to make the project already, my problem is I'm trying to return the number total of Fizz, Buzz and Fizzbuzz respectively in the end. And return statements dont work for me, any help please? 
My code:

```
using System;

namespace FizzBuzz
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
            {
                //Declaration of Fizz and Buzz as Boolean
                bool fizz = i % 3 == 0;
                bool buzz = i % 5 == 0;
                //Fizzbuzz declared to be conditional if its both
                bool fizzbuzz = fizz && buzz;
                if (fizzbuzz)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("FizzBuzz"); 
                }
                else if (fizz)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Fizz");
                }
                else if (i % 5 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Buzz");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you store the results of your `fizz` checks somewhere?

Comment: What does that mean: `and return statements dont work for me`? Does it mean that they don't work because you need to return multiple values? You can create a class with three properties and set the value there, you can return a tuple, you can use `out` parameters.

Comment: Yes, it won't let me return return multiple values.

Comment: Return object or array

Comment: Return a Tuple.

Comment: No, I have not worked with Dictionary before

Comment: You are learning that it is a bad idea to make methods that are useful for both their side effects and their values. Your method is useful for its side effects, so do not return the values; make another side effect. Print them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
using System;

namespace FizzBuzz
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                int fizzCount = 0;
                int buzzCount = 0;
                int fizzbuzzCount = 0;
                for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
                {
                    //Declaration of Fizz and Buzz as Boolean
                    bool fizz = i % 3 == 0;
                    bool buzz = i % 5 == 0;
                    //Fizzbuzz declared to be conditional if its both
                    bool fizzbuzz = fizz && buzz;

                    if (fizzbuzz)
                    {
                       fizzbuzzCount++;
                       Console.WriteLine("FizzBuzz");
                    }
                    else if (fizz)
                    {
                        fizzCount++;
                        Console.WriteLine("Fizz");
                    }
                    else if (buzz)
                    {
                        buzzCount++;
                        Console.WriteLine("Buzz");
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(i);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Fizz count: " + fizzCount.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Buzz count: " + buzzCount.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("FizzBuzz count: " + fizzbuzzCount.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i did'nt think about initiating them like that, the code does send me back this error for all three though The name 'buzzCount' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I wrote the code on my phone. Just make sure there aren't any syntax errors. Visual studio will tell you whats wrong when you try to run it.

Comment: Managed to get it working. Thank you soo much for the help, All I have to do now is make it so it only shows the total in the end only